# Put the drive letter in the path

Tags: powershell

```cs
$DiskCount = (Get-Disk | Where-Object {$_.BusType -eq "USB"}).Number.Count
if ($DiskCount -eq 1) {
    filter Get-FirstResolvedPath {
       (Get-Disk |
           Where-Object {$_.BusType -eq "USB"} |
           Get-Partition |
           Get-Volume |
           Where-Object {$null -ne $_.DriveLetter}
       ).DriveLetter + ':\' | Join-Path -ChildPath $_ -Resolve -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
    'Folder\Folder\reg\Start.reg' | Get-FirstResolvedPath
}
```

Is there another method to get full path to the file, if it stores on USB drive, the path is absolute, and we don't know USB disk letter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like your solution. I would write it differently, and you could shorten it a bit:

```
function Get-ResolvedPath {
  param ([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=1)]$Path)
  Get-Disk |? BusType -ne USB | Get-Partition |% {Join-Path ($_.DriveLetter+":") $Path -R -EA Silent}
}

'Folder\Folder\reg\Start.reg' | Get-ResolvedPath | select -First 1
```

Comment: I know about -first 1, but script won't run correctly, if certain file (start.reg) is on the "seecond" drive. So I'm in serach of rational method...

Comment: @farag Specify "does not run correctly"? I can't think of a reason why this wouldn't work.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But how use it if I prefer (Get-Disk | Where-Object {$_.BusType -eq "USB"} | Get-Partition).DriveLetter construction?

Comment: @farag `(Get-Disk | Where-Object {$_.BusType -eq "USB"} | Get-Partition).DriveLetter |% {Join-Path ($_+":") $Path -R -EA Silent}` but I don't see why you would want to use that.